# Convert list of Dictionaries of lists to DataFrame Table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that i'd like to convert into a data frame table. I know the question in the title is a little confusing, so ill post the dictionary:

```
[{'MESSAGE': ['RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS'], 'BIN': ['8FHA9D83H 82HG7D9F'], 'INV': 'SSXR   98-20LM NM CORN CREAM'}, {'MESSAGE': ['RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS', '#2956- INVALID STOCK COUPON CODE (MISSING).', 'RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS'], 'BIN': ['HA8DHWO2H HAHD0138', '8SHDNAIDU 00AD0123', '938273548 0967HDBR'], 'INV': 'FPBC   *SOUP CANS LENTILS'}]
```

I've tried many methods of Pandas, but because there are multiple values for each key, it's a slightly harder problem to solve. I've tried to tweak conventional methods of pd.DataFrame, but i can't quite figure it out. I need the df table to show this output when printed:

```
         BIN               INV CODE                          MESSAGE                                                   
8FHA9D83H82HG7D9F   SSXR-98-20LM NM CORN CREAM  RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS
HA8DHWO2HHAHD0138     FPBC-*SOUP CANS LENTILS    RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS          
8SHDNAIDU00AD0123     FPBC-*SOUP CANS LENTILS    #2956- INVALID STOCK COUPON CODE (MISSING).          
9382735480967HDBR     FPBC-*SOUP CANS LENTILS    RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS
```

I'm pretty new to Python 2.7, so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming L is your list of dicts:

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(l) for l in L)

Out: 
                  BIN                           INV  \
0  8FHA9D83H 82HG7D9F  SSXR   98-20LM NM CORN CREAM   
0  HA8DHWO2H HAHD0138     FPBC   *SOUP CANS LENTILS   
1  8SHDNAIDU 00AD0123     FPBC   *SOUP CANS LENTILS   
2  938273548 0967HDBR     FPBC   *SOUP CANS LENTILS   

                                           MESSAGE  
0  RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS  
0  RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS  
1      #2956- INVALID STOCK COUPON CODE (MISSING).  
2  RECEIVED SUCCESSFULLY AWAITING STOCKING PROCESS
```